# How to run Microsoft To Do from command line or from AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, command-line, autohotkey, microsoft-todo

How to open Microsoft To Do (2.56.43053) from command line of Windows 10 Enterprise (1909). I need this answer in order to create keyboard shortcut to AutoHotkey. There might be also be another way to open the program in AutoHotkey.

So far, I have managed to open Microsoft To Do from Windows menu

[image]

or from taskbar

[image].

However, I did not find way to launch Microsoft To Do from command line.

From the properties of "Microsoft To Do" in Task Manager, I found that the program is located in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`, however, I do not have access to the folder from the command prompt.

It is weird to have a program which can be launched from the menu or taskbar, but cannot be launched otherwise.

Comment: This question was originally prematurely closed. However, first answerer already provided a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read on different sources, you would have to set this up yourself.

Even though I think you should be able to launch any Microsoft app from the command line (other than the microsoft store app with the command: start ms-windows-store), like Linux does, not every app supports that from what I see.

These are the sources that I have read about how to do the setup of launching Microsoft apps from the command line.

**Microsoft Community:** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675

**Tent Forums:** https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/57000-method-open-any-windows-10-apps-command-line.html

**Edit by Heikki (questioner)**:

According to the links you may

- first **create a shortcut** from the original application and
- then **call the shortcut** from the command line: `"Microsoft To Do.lnk"`

Comment: Thanks! Edited the solution as part of the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: If you found the question you answered well formed and useful, you may use your [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) moderator priviledge gained at 15 reputation.

Comment: I already did after answering your question, but thanks for letting me know.